# Extended navigation drawer can't change activity. What's going on?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have created a BaseActivity class with navigation drawer and the other class CheckList extends the BaseActivity to have a navigation drawer.

In BaseActivity, I can change the activity to CheckList through navigation drawer.
But in CheckList. Even I can see the drawer, it is not work for changing class.

BaseActivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
protected ListView drawerList;

protected ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
protected CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
protected CharSequence mTitle;

protected String[] drawer_menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initActionBar();
    initDrawer();
    initDrawerList();
}

protected void initActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
}

protected void initDrawer() {
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

protected void initDrawerList() {
    drawer_menu = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_menu);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawer_menu);
    drawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

//respond when click the ic_drawer
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

protected void selectItem(int position) {
    //Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent main = new Intent();
            main.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(main);
            finish();
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent checklist = new Intent();
            checklist.setClass(getApplicationContext(), CheckList.class);
            startActivity(checklist);
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    /*FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();*/

    drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(drawer_menu[position]);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

CheckList:

```
public class CheckList extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button addBtn;
ListView listView;

ArrayList<String> checkListItem;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.checklist, drawerLayout);

    addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listItems);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    checkListItem = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, checkListItem);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    checkListItem.add(getString(R.string.cl_passport));
    checkListItem.add(getString(R.string.cl_charger));
    checkListItem.add(getString(R.string.cl_camera));

    registerForContextMenu(listView);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.checklist_contextmenu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cl_contextmenu_delete:
            checkListItem.remove(info.position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        case R.id.cl_contextmenu_edit:
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckList.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.cl_editItem));
            final EditText edit = new EditText(this);
            edit.setText(checkListItem.get(info.position));
            edit.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            alertDialog.setView(edit);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    checkListItem.set(info.position, edit.getText().toString());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==this.addBtn) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CheckList.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.cl_input));
        final EditText checkListInput = new EditText(this);
        alertDialog.setView(checkListInput);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                checkListItem.add(checkListInput.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
}
```

I can't simply change the class to MainActivity in CheckList. But in BaseActivity, I can change to both MainActivity and CheckList.

Many thanks !!

---

Updated
This is my drawer.xml file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- Add content here -->
</FrameLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#e5e5e5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#d6d6d6"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You're inflating `R.layout.checklist` into the `drawerLayout`, which is adding the new layout over the drawer, with respect to z-order. You need to inflate it into the content ViewGroup within the DrawerLayout instead.

Comment: What should I do? I am new in writing android.... Could you explain more to me?

Comment: Please edit your question to add your `drawer` layout XML file, and I can be more specific.

Comment: Is the drawer drawing out or not?

Comment: I can draw out the drawer. The drawer items are also shown. But when I click the item let said checklist, it can't lead me to the CheckList activity. (It works in the BaseActivity only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unable to click on the drawer's list items because you're inflating the `CheckList` Activity's layout directly into the `DrawerLayout` of the `BaseActivity`. This is causing it to be "on top" of all of the `DrawerLayout`'s child `View`s, and your clicks won't propagate through to the drawer `ListView` underneath. Instead, you want to inflate `CheckList`'s layout into the `content_frame` `FrameLayout` within the `DrawerLayout`.

In the `BaseActivity` class add a `protected` field for the `FrameLayout`, and initialize it just like the other `View`s.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    protected ListView drawerList;
    protected FrameLayout contentFrame;
    ...

    protected void initDrawer() {
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        contentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        ...
    }
}
```

Then change the `inflate()` call in `CheckList` as follows:

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.checklist, contentFrame);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It solved my problem! I want to know more about this. What is the FrameLayout mean here? Is that mean now I have 3 layer. The lowest is the drawer with the FrameLayout. The middle one is checklist.xml that I put it on the top of the drawer.xml. The top layer is the draw item? So I can propagate directly to the item? Sorry for asking this stupid question...;(

Comment: I'm probably not going to explain this very well, but: The DrawerLayout is the root View of your Activity; the main parent View. It holds both its content FrameLayout, and its drawer, the ListView in this case. Views are added to their parent in the order they're listed, with respect to z-order, so the ListView, being last, is on top of the FrameLayout, and you can click on it. When you inflate CheckList's layout into the FrameLayout, its Views are now children of the FrameLayout, and are underneath the drawer. You're kind of inserting CheckList's Views in between the root View and the drawer.